# Is it possible to initialize a library?

Tags: dart

I am trying out the new Dart FFI in making wrappers for libsodium. Libsodium needs to be initialized with calling `init()`. But I don't think the user should be burdened to remember this and I also wouldn't like to check some global state variable.

I know that Go has package `init()` functions which run when a package gets included. Is there something similar in Dart?

Of course I could just wrap everything up into a class and run `init()` in the constructor but there isn't much sense in instatiating a class which basically only exposes static methods. Besides, I would like to preserve the procedural style of libsodium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart does not have any way to implicitly run code. No code runs before `main`, and all code running after `main` does so because it was invoked directly or indirectly from the `main` method. So, no.

If you need something initialized, there is a number of options.

- You can use a lazily initialized static variable:

  ```
  var _initialState = _init();
  int doSomething(arguments) {
    _initialState;
    do the something.
  }
  ```

  The reading of `_initialState` will ensure that `init` is invoked the first time
  it's needed, and not after that. You can even store things in the state for 
  later use.
- The singleton implementation object suggested by @jamesdlin. It basically does the 
  same thing, then puts the methods on the object instead of being static. 
  Another variant is to do exactly that, but with a private instance, and have the 
  public top-level functions forward to the singleton object. Then you get the 
  procedural API and still ensures that the state object is initialized.
  (This may be better for testing, allowing you to have multiple state objects alive
  at the same time).
- Require people to call `init`.

Answer (score 4):

> Of course I could just wrap everything up into a class and run init() in the constructor but there isn't much sense in instatiating a class which basically only exposes static methods. Besides, I would like to preserve the procedural style of libsodium.

You could have a singleton instance and expose library functions as methods on the instance, and you could provide a public getter function that automatically does initialization.

For example, something like:

```dart
Libsodium? _instance;
Libsodium get libsodium => _instance ??= Libsodium._();

class Libsodium {
  Libsodium._() {
    // Do initialization.
  }

  void foo() {
    // ...
  }
  
  void bar() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

or, taking advantage of Dart initializing global and `static` variables lazily, that can be simplified to:

```dart
final Libsodium libsodium = Libsodium._();

class Libsodium {
  ...
}
```

and then callers would need to use it via:

```dart
import 'libsodium.dart';

libsodium.foo();
```

This would hide the class instantiation and wouldn't look any different to callers than if you were to use only top-level functions with a namespace (`import 'libsodium.dart' as libsodium`).